# Compare Swagger Specs in .NET

Tags: c#, unit-tests, rest

I need to compare Swagger specifications in a C# unit test.

The only reliable tool that I have been able to find is [swagger-diff](https://github.com/civisanalytics/swagger-diff) but it is written in Ruby. It fulfills all of my requirements except for the fact that it require Ruby and I need this to run in a .NET unit test.

What tools can you recommend?

Comment: By "specification" do you mean a document (for instance in English) describing a technology, for instance [this specification](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/3.0.0.md)? If yes, do you want to compare two versions of a specification? If yes, why do it in a unit test?

Comment: @NicolasRaoul I basically need contract checking to check forwards and backwards compatibility

Comment: A "specification" is a JSON file that describes a REST API, using the Open API Initiative format, if I understand correctly?

Comment: @NicolasRaoul correct